# How do I transform the dynamic type of log data that vary over time, with static type for data that I use to train my Machine learning algorithm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, data-science, bigdata

I work on a project which have as a principal purpose A creation of a prediction system failures in servers which is based on analyzing the log file. In addition to that I have to use some algorithms as SVM. for the moment I do not know how transormer the dynamic type of log data that vary over time, with static type for data that I use to train my algorithm I would be grateful for any help or proposals .